# Differential Equation: Initial Value Problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve explicitly the initial value problem: $x^2y'+xy=2+x^2$,  $y(1) = 2 $

In the solution, they begin by dividing by $x^2$ to normalize the ODE, and multiply both RHS and LHS by the integrating factor x, yielding the integrable problem

> $xy'+y=\frac{2}{x}+x, y(1)=2.$

Then they say *by inspection*, $(xy)'=\frac{2}{x}+x,$ ignoring the y on the LHS.

So, why do they ignore y? Doesn't y change with respect to x, meaning that the y on the LHS contributes to the equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Product rule:

$$ (xy)' = x'y + xy' = y + xy' $$

using that

$$ \frac{d}{dx} x = 1 $$

Comment: I don't think this answers the question "why do they ignore $y$".  Though maybe it does because I can't understand what that's supposed to mean. $\huge\cdot$__$\huge\cdot$

Comment: @Bye_World: you should think about it more. The OP's question states that he doesn't see why $(xy)'$ and $xy' + y$ are the same, thinking that the first one is "ignoring $y$".

Comment: Ah -- the "ignoring the $y$ on the LHS" is not part of what "they say".  Got it.

Comment: Hum... punctuation in addition to italics would certainly have helped there.

Comment: Aha! thank you very much for insight. I've been staring at this equation for a good 5 minutes until I resorted to stack exchange.